# Jest: Can set function as mock, but not equivalent object method

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm not able to have an object method mock correctly:

```
const getItem = jest.fn(key => key);
localStorage = {
  getItem
};
console.log(getItem('test')); // 'test'
console.log(localStorage.getItem('test')); // null
```

Just in case there was an issue with the variable name I tried this after commenting the above:

```
 localStorage = jest.fn(key => key);
 console.log(localStorage('test2')); // 'test2'
```

In the target file I assign the object and property to the global, as I found this to work with `fetch`:

```
// target file used by the test runner file:
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  fetch = window.fetch;
  localStorage = window.localStorage;
  localStorage.getItem = window.localStorage.getItem;
} else {
  fetch = global.fetch;
  localStorage = global.localStorage;
  localStorage.getItem = global.localStorage.getItem;
}
```

**Also tried**

ES5 property assignment (getItem : getItem). No change

```
const getItem = jest.fn(key => key);
global.localStorage = {
  getItem
};
console.log(global.localStorage.getItem('test')); // null
```

It also logs null without global. inside the log argument.

What else could be preventing localStorage.getItem() from working as intended?

Comment: Try this 

const getItem = jest.fn(key => key);
global.localStorage = {
  getItem
};

Comment: Why use `localStorage = {getItem}` instead of `localStorage.getItem = val => getItem(val)`?

Comment: @NickA separate mock assignments let jest spies count calls on each property individually

Comment: @OgieSado Doesn't fix it unfortunately